# jQuery Validate plugin is validating a field which has become "disabled"

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a field `gender?` which enables `is Pregnant?` if gender is set to FEMALE,

then if `is Pregnant?` field is unanswered, it's flagged as invalid.

If you go back and set `gender?` to MALE  The validation still flags `is Pregnant?` as invalid, even though it has been `disabled`.

jQuery says `disabled` fields are ignored.  I even tried: 
[jquery.validate validating disabled field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403332/jquery-validate-validating-disabled-field)

```
ignore: ":hidden"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: because  MALE  never pragnent so  "is Pregnant?"as invalid

Comment: Yes, if Gender is MALE, "is Pregnant?" is disabled and should not be validated. But it is still being validated >_<

Comment: I think you still need to ignore `:disabled`, since you are disabling it and not hiding it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is a valid problem, with this markup

```
<form>
<div>
    Male:
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" />
    Female:
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" /></div>
<br />
<div>
    Pregnant:
    <input type="radio" name="pregnant" value="yes" />
    Not Pregnant:
    <input type="radio" name="pregnant" value="no" /></div>
<br />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

and this script

```
$('[name=gender]').click(function () {
    var disabled = $(this).val() === 'male';
    $('[name=pregnant]').attr('disabled', disabled);

    // UNCOMMENT THIS TO FIX 
    // if ($('[name=pregnant]').hasClass('error')) {
    //    $('form').validate().form();
    // }
});

$('input').addClass('required');

$('form').validate({
    ignore: ":disabled",
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        error.appendTo(element.parent("div"));
    },
    submitHandler: function () {
        alert('form is ok');
    }
});
```

to reproduce the problem:

- click female
- click submit
- error message shows - this is correct
- click male - error message still shows
- click submit - form is valid

so as @ioan says you need to try and get rid of this error message as it is confusing, even though the form is valid the error message is still there

- problem -  http://jsfiddle.net/YzCHJ/4/
- a possible solution -  http://jsfiddle.net/YzCHJ/5/

Comment: Thank you, lovely answer.  ^__^

Answer (score 2):

The `.validate()` `ignore:` option works as follows:

> **ignore**, Default: `":hidden"`
>   Elements to ignore when validating, simply filtering them out. jQuery's not-method is
>   used, therefore **everything that is accepted by `not()` can be passed** as this option.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions

**Working Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/us9aE/

**HTML:**

```
<form id="myform">   
     <input type="text" name="field" disabled="disabled" /> <br/> 
</form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myform').validate({
        ignore: ":disabled"
    });
});
```

If you'd like more specific help, please show your relevant HTML, your jQuery, and optionally create a jsFiddle demo.

Comment: I was trying to add this to the individual rules. Adding it to the form itself solved it for me

Comment: @edank, none of the options get added to the `rules`.   All of this plugin's options are siblings of the `rules` object.

Answer (score 0):

The disabled fields are ignored during the validation phase BUT if the validation phase comes into action before the field has been disabled, the error message will still be there.

You can try to simply remove the validation message by cleaning the validation errors and re-validate the form.

Comment: Am I not missing some validation options?  I've tried
    onfocusout: true

Comment: I don't think you have to set additional validation options, I had exactly the same issue and I fixed that by forcing re-validation. Maybe this is not the best idea, but that worked fine in my case.

Comment: How did you force validation?  I tried placing $('#myForm').validate() in $('#isGender').change() but it did not work T_T

Comment: $('#myForm').validate().form(); or $('#myForm').validate().element("name of the element")

Comment: More simply, `$('#myForm').valid()` will re-trigger a validation check of the form.